# Is there some way of using the safe null operator for an object that doesn't exist?

Tags: groovy

Is there something like "?" that can return null or false if an object doesn't exist.

This throws an error:

```
println doesntExist['sdfsd'​]​
```

This doesn't work but is there a way to use "?" somehow to get a boolean?

```
println doesntExist?['sdfsd'​]​
println doesntExist['sdfsd'​]​?
println ?doesntExist['sdfsd'​]​
```

Is there a groovyier way to do this:

```
if (doesntExist && doesntExist['sdfsd'​]​ ){}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get()` or `getAt()` method which is equivalent of array index access operator:

```
def doesntExist = null

println doesntExist?.getAt('sdfsd')
println doesntExist?.get('sdfsd')
```

Output:

```
null
null
```

#### Explanation

If you compile the code containing:

```
doesntExist['sdfsd']
```

and open its decompiled version (e.g. in IntelliJ IDEA) you will see that this part compiles to

```
DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(doesntExist, "sdfsd")
```

That is why if you want to use null safe operator you have to call

```
doesntExist?.getAt('sdfsd')
```

directly.

Comment: coooollll. this is opinion at this point but is that considered a standard approach for this in groovy? or is doing it the long way considered more readable by groovy people?

Comment: @red888 No, this is actually a fact. Groovy compiles `doesntExist['sdfsd']` to `DefaultGroovyMethods.getAt(doesntExist, "sdfsd")`, so if you want to make index operator null safe you have to make this call `doesntExist?.getAt('sdfsd')` direct call.